Using a coupled inductor in a multi phase buck converter - how to set the inductor dot notation and converter PWM for best ripple reduction
Based on these Charles Sullivan papers, we can use a coupled inductor in a multi phase converter to reduce inductor ripple current.
https://www.princeton.edu/~minjie/files/sullivan-CICC-2021.pdf
http://inductor.thayerschool.org/papers/coupL.pdf
I am still confused on the polarity/phase of the inductor and converter PWM in order to achieve this ripple reduction. Assume we have a 2 phase buck converter, then we have the 4 possibilities below. Which one will achieve the best current ripple reduction (assuming inductor coupling is held constant)? Further, will there be any benefit with flux reduction in any of these configuration?


Same polarity coupled inductor and converter PWMs in phase



2) Reverse polarity coupled inductor and converter PWMs in phase


3) Reverse polarity coupled inductor and converter PWMs 180 out of phase


4) Same polarity coupled inductor and converter PWMs 180 out of phase


Well, we can eliminate the first two cases quickly: what are the ripple currents compared to a single phase of same total rating, and what effect does coupling have? For (3) and (4), what does the simulation show?

I suspect the circuit schematics require at least one (1) filter inductor (choke) to be inserted between the coupled inductors and the output capacitor.  This is the case for all the circuits shown in the two references you provided.  If so, please update the schematics in your question.  [Refer fig 2 of the APEC2002 paper, and fig 10 of the 2021 paper]

You should use a simulator and find out directly.
